# Nginx blocking user that request location with "admin" in root directory (only)

Tags: regex, nginx, filter

We use nginx and in an effort to stop all users that are trying to find our secret admin url we wanted to add a nginx location rule:

Looking in location where 
- the first directory/folder contains the word admin 
- followed by anything after that 
- but not excluding /xxxx/adminhtml/ where the word admin is found in the second folder or route - whereby the second folder or route can be any string containing admin

Test cases (there are ofcourse more, as an example):

- /admin => stop
- /admin/badurl.php => stop
- /admin/route/openaccess.php => stop
- /cpadmin/  => stop
- /admin/adminhtml => stop
- /cpadminbackend/  => stop
- /adminbackend/route/openaccess.php  => stop
- /xxx/myadminfolder/ => OK
- /xxx/admin/myroute/ => OK
- /xyz/route/folderwithadmininit/ => OK

Our code so far

```
Drop people trying to access admin
location ~* /.*admin.*\/.*/ {
  return 444;
}
```

or maybe

```
location ~* /.*admin[^\/]*\/.*/ {
  return 444;
}
```

But it seems they are either not working or maybe to greedy ...

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your rule could be created as:

```
location ~* ^/[^/]*admin
```

The breakdown is:

- anchor to the beginning so that we catch the first directory component
- allow zero or more non-`/` characters
- catch `admin` in the first directory component

More on regex syntax can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: @snh_nl Updated answer

Comment: Ahhh so less is more in this case! Let me test and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
location ~* /(admin|adminbackend|cpadmin|cpadminbackend)/
```